# HTML inside TextArea?

Tags: html

So I have this textarea in my website. By default, it has something like this as its contents:

```
Name : Sample Value
Age : Sample Value
Location : Sample Value
```

It is editable before the user hits the button and inserts it into the database, although I am not using a rich text editor since it's nothing but a simple text.

Since basic HTML codes are not browser readable inside the textarea tag, I used `&#10;` to separate lines.

Now my problem is that I am not able to include the HTML code when I'm reading the value of the textarea tag in the server side.

Thus, the value inserted to the database is not HTML formatted as well, and when it is once again fetched into a web browser, it has no format at all.

What alternatives do I have? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible using `textarea`, use `contenteditable` DIV instead.

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

You can use getters and setter as shown below:

```
//Get content    
var contents = document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML; 

//Set content
document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = contents
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) is the browser support for this approach.

Comment: Ok. But how do I get the value of the div? Sorry, that is new to me.

Comment: @Ash: *why*? It's been supported in browsers since Firefox 3.5, IE 5.5, Safari 3.1...it's clearly *not* restricted to [tag:html5]. Reference: [`contentEditable` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable).

Comment: @christianleroy use id of that contenteditable and get textContent. 
document.getElementById(DIV_ID).textContent

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JQuery and do this $(textarea).val() to get the value of the textarea as a string and use it server side. you might have to  consider using Ajax to make a call to the server side method you want to pass the Html data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple.
Use contenteditable `DIV`s instead of `TextBox` and `TextArea`.
But remember to add `contenteditable="false"` to all your inner HTML tags.

This worked for me.